# Choosing three values in a field, and showing all the documents which show those chosen values

Tags: mongodb

I have documents which contain a name field. I am trying to randomly select 3 of those names, and then show all documents associated with those three names.

This is what I have so far:

```
db.collection.aggregate({$group: {"_id": "$name"}},{$limit: 3},{$match: {"name": "$_id"}});
```

I'm new to mongodb, so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try an **OR** statement?

```
db.inventory.aggregate(
   [
       {
           $project:
          {
               item: 1,
               result: { $or: [ { $eq: [ "$name", "$_id" ] }, { $eq: [ "$_id", "$name" ] } ] }
          }
       }
   ]
)
```

But I am not sure I have understood what you mean.